# Core Dumped on example

Tags: c++14, valgrind, sfml

After a lot of researching I couldn't find any useful answer to my problem so here I am !

Context:
I want to do a cellular automata representation using C++ & SFML
I used to use SFML on some distribution but recently moved to Ubuntu and tried ton install SFML

After plenty of linking error and undefined reference, I finally managed to compile the example from SFML tutorial !

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my makefile

```
NAME    =       SFMLFire                                                        

CC      =       g++                                                             

SRCS    =       main.cpp                                                        

OBJS    =       $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)                                                 

CXXFLAGS=       -L/home/kopo/SFML-2.4.2/lib/ -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-window-d \
-lsfml-system-d -Wall -Werror -std=c++14 -I./include/ -I/home/kopo/SFML-2.4.2/i\
nclude                                                                          

RM      =       rm -fr                                                          

all     :       $(NAME)                                                         

$(NAME) :       $(OBJS)                                                         
                $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(CXXFLAGS)                            

clean   :                                                                       
                $(RM) $(OBJS)                                                   

fclean  :       clean                                                           
                $(RM) $(NAME)                                                   

re      :       fclean all                                                      

.PHONY  :       all re clean fclean
```

Now for the problem:
It segfaults ! Core Dumped. I'm pretty sure it's not from the code since I ran on my previous distribution without problem

I saw some people saying it might come from the lib being 32/64 bits or openGl driver not being installed, but I'm almost certain that this is not the problem here

I also added LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/SFML/lib" to my bashrc just in case

I tried using Valgrind to have more information, but Valgrind makes the program run as intended

So I'm kinda lost, do you see anything that seems wrong in my code or makefile ?
Do you have any suggestions on what could be the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: And *where* do the crash happens? *When*? If you run a debug-build in a debugger, where in your code does it happen? Perhaps you should take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: As a hint though: Think about what happens if you close the window, and then you try to draw in it.

Comment: Using gdb, it crashes after the
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
So I tried removing anything related to sf::CircleShape, hoping to simply have an empty window opening
But it still crashes just after this 
Thanks for the article, I'll give it a read

Regarding your hint, I guess that when I close the window, the pointer is freed hence I cannot draw in it, but I don't see how it applies to my problem since the programm crash as soon as I execute it

Comment: The article was indeed a nice read, but I am almost certain that the problem doesn't come from the code, but from my system. I tried anything I could and read all that seemed relevant in vain. I ran out of idea and so this post

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem... and I'm ashamed...

I downloaded the SDK from SFML, SDK meant for GCC
And I tried to compile it with G++